# UIAutomation.RangeValuePattern: different behavior UIVerify vs my own test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

### Situation

I need to write a test for the program with a slider: [Picture #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf5ex.jpg)

When I use UIVerify, slider works and program responses on SetValue (not only control chages the value, but business logic reacts on a new value too). The only problem - range limits are not equal to labels [-90;90] on the form and [0;100] in UIVerify:[Picture #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf5ex.jpg)

But in my test-program slider control behaviors completely different. First of all I get different limits and current value for the same control in the same time (in parallel) : (Picture #3)

But the main problem is: when I invoke SetValue in my test-programm - slider chages "thumb" possition but bussines layer doesn't see any changes.
I've tried VS2008(UI Automation 3.0) & VS2012(UI Automation 4.0) - problem the same. Version of UI Verify is 2.0. I found sources of UI Verify on CodePlex and found out that UI Verify works not via .net UI Automation but via Com Wrapers (in other words it has his own implementation of .net UI Automation).

### Temporary solution

I'm  invoking increase-decrease after SetValue to notify bussines logic. But I hope to find better solution! :-)

Comment: Com Wrappers use native UI Automation dlls which haven't some bugs that .NET version has. I've seen similar discussions on SO but cannot find the links quickly.